# How can I change the child option when the parent option is changed

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5, optionmenu

I'm trying to change the child option when the parent option gets changed for instance this is what happens with bootstrap

`

```
<div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
                    <span class="label-input100">Industry *</span>
                    <div>
                        <select class="js-select2" name="service">
                            <option>Please choose</option>
                            <option>Real Estate</option>
                            <option>Construction</option>
                            <option>Technology</option>
                            <option>Food</option>
                            <option>Entertainment</option>
                            <option>Fashion</option>
                            <option>General Contract</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w-full dis-none js-show-service real-estate-services">
                    <div class="wrap-contact100-form-radio">
                        <span class="label-input100">What service do you need?</span>
                        <div class="contact100-form-radio m-t-15">
                            <input class="input-radio100" id="radio1" type="radio" name="type-product" value="physical"
                                checked="checked">
                            <label class="label-radio100" for="radio1">
                                Buying
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact100-form-radio">
                            <input class="input-radio100" id="radio2" type="radio" name="type-product" value="digital">
                            <label class="label-radio100" for="radio2">
                                Selling
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact100-form-radio">
                            <input class="input-radio100" id="radio3" type="radio" name="type-product" value="service">
                            <label class="label-radio100" for="radio3">
                                Renting
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

`

If I click the real estate option the other option under shows up, I want the options to change to a different option list when I switch from real estate to construction or any of the parent option

Is there any way to do that with Bootstrap, jQuery or vanilla javascript

I tried using bootstrap but can't figure out how to make the child options change when i select a different parent option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a concept called events.
you can listen to some even happening (event listener), so you need to listen for a "change" event on the child select tag - `<select onchange="someFunction()">...` then in the function - find the parent by `document.quesrySelector` function or `document.getElementById()` function, then manipulate the parent's value property the to new one you want